# How to get Attachment file sizes in SharePoint 2007 in a SOAP request

Tags: sharepoint, soap, attachment, filesize, caml

I have a custom list on a sharepoint server. Each list item contains multiple file attachments . I am connecting to server with a SOAP-envelope request with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<soap12:Body>
<GetListItems xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/">
<listName>{A6888F11-0C37-4411-BC6D-1C9BA869B250}</listName>
<queryOptions>
<QueryOptions> 
<IncludeMandatoryColumns>FALSE</IncludeMandatoryColumns>
<ViewAttributes Scope="RecursiveAll"/>
<DateInUtc>TRUE</DateInUtc>
<IndividualProperties>TRUE</IndividualProperties>
<IncludeAttachmentUrls>TRUE</IncludeAttachmentUrls>
</QueryOptions>
</queryOptions>
</GetListItems>
</soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

The response is good, and I see a list of the URLs for each attachment. However, I am trying to also get the file size of each one in this request. What do I need to add in order to obtain this information?